# Why is a "psychological problem" off topic?

Tags: discussion

So I was pointed in the direction of [this discussion](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1246) on meta and I'm wondering why a 'psychological problem' is off topic? Why can't there be a life hack that can deal with such issues?

In the particular example where an alarm was sub consciously turned off why is saying place the alarm out of reach not a valid lifehack? am I missing something? now I'm sure that there are more complex examples than this and it may be a bit of common sense and voted down/closed because of this but I'm concerned that all 'psychological problem' are off limits.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I don't always agree with how it is applied, I do understand why narrowing the scope of the site is needed.

"Psychological" questions can tend to be a little too dependent on the person asking. As in what works for one may not work for others. This can lead to an "every answer is equally valid" situation, which doesn't work well on SE's Q&A format.

Take an example like:

> "How do I increase concentration in a boring meeting?"

The answer for me would probably be along the lines of:

> "Bring a strong cup of coffee into the meeting"

But while caffeine works well for me it may make others jittery and more distracted.

SE works best when things are a little less subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, **because that's what [our scope](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/the-scope-of-lifehacks) says**. Our definition of a lifehack is one that deals with *physical problems*,  not psychological ones.

As for the reasoning behind why we included this clarification in our definition and scope, it's because without it our scope was too broad. We can't be catch-all a site that accepts all questions where it's possible for us to help the OP. We were receiving questions that only work on an individual basis that are not very applicable to others, which is the opposite of what we want and what the Q&A format of the SE network requires. Physical lifehacks may not be available for certain people, but the lifehack itself can be tested and judged to see if it works with the supplies specified. With psychological lifehacks that's not the case - it depends on the person testing.

It also opens up the possibility of arguing that *anything* is a lifehack because psychology is involved in everything that we do day to day. This creates a broad scope that is impossible to properly apply uniformly as it would be determined by each person's opinions of the problem at hand.